# Touchpad stuck in horizontal scroll box

Tags: touchpad, multi-touch

Using two-fingered scrolling on the trackpad has become second nature to me as a former user of OS X.

I made the switch recently to Ubuntu 18.04 and am surprised to find how difficult two-fingered scrolling is here.

If you find yourself in a box which scrolls horizontally such as [this code box](https://redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started#basic-example) , or [this AskUbuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1069974/269136) it becomes impossible to continue scrolling the page.

Any two-fingered movement is 'captured' by the horizontal scroll box and scrolls that box left and right, rather than scrolling the page up and down.

This is particularly acute in environments like [Jupyter Notebook](https://jupyter.org/) where boxes are regularly wider than they are tall.

I don't want to disable horizontal scrolling altogether, since it does have valid use cases. But where the box under the cursor doesn't scroll vertically, the default should be to scroll the page instead.

Do I have any options here? Seems to me like this should work out of the box.

---

Details:

I'm on an HP Pavilion laptop with Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Accidentally, isn't that Firefox where you see that behavior? Or is that true for other apps/browsers as well?

Comment: @Hi-Angel Good point: This is happening in Chrome.

Comment: Wow. Funny *(or not)*, but in this case it works more correctly in Firefox than in Chrome. I can reproduce the problem in Chromium and Qutebrowser *(based on the same engine)*, but not in Firefox. Anyway, this is a Chrome bug. From a cursory search I didn't find it reported, so you might as well be the first :)

Comment: To clarify about Firefox: they make scroll to stick to vertical or horizontal axis, which is okay though, that was just a thought about what could you've been seeing. But they don't make it "stuck", i.e. there shouldn't be a problem with that.